# Location me in map from React Leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I want to ask if I use a map from React Leaflet (https://react-leaflet.js.org/) but how do I add a location button to the map? like this an example of the location me button in the image that I gave the red arrow

And pictures in the link: 
[Example of an arrow Location Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvcgG.jpg)

[An example on my map where I want to add location Me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ei7l.png)

And how to show the location button, where do you save it from my coding?

```
import { React, useState } from 'react'
import {
  LayersControl,
  MapContainer,
  Marker,
  Popup,
  TileLayer,
  useMapEvents,
} from 'react-leaflet'

const { BaseLayer } = LayersControl

function LocationMarker() {
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(null)
  const map = useMapEvents({
    click() {
      map.locate()
    },
    locationfound(e) {
      setPosition(e.latlng)
      map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom())
    },
  })

  return position === null ? null : (
    <Marker position={position}>
      <Popup>You are here</Popup>
    </Marker>
  )
}


function MapsMe() {
  return (
    <div className="flex ml-auto">
      <div className="w-4/5">
        <MapContainer center={51.505, -0.09} zoom=20>
          <LayersControl>
            <BaseLayer checked name="OpenStreetMap">
              <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png "
              />
            </BaseLayer>
            <LocationMarker />
          </LayersControl>
        </MapContainer>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default MapsMe
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get the exact same result as in your picture you need to use
`leaflet-easybutton` library with `font-awesome`. Otherwise you can easily build your own icon by extending leaflet control.

Install them:

```
npm i leaflet-easybutton

npm i font-awesome
```

Import them:

```
import "leaflet-easybutton/src/easy-button.js";
import "leaflet-easybutton/src/easy-button.css";
import "font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css";
```

Instantiate `L.easy-button` using fa-map-marker icon and inside the callback save the position and move the map to the user location.

```
export default function Map() {
  const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
  const [position, setPosition] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!map) return;

    L.easyButton("fa-map-marker", () => {
      map.locate().on("locationfound", function (e) {
        setPosition(e.latlng);
        map.flyTo(e.latlng, map.getZoom());
      });
    }).addTo(map);
  }, [map]);

  return (
    <MapContainer
      center={[51.505, -0.09]}
      zoom={20}
      style={{ height: "100vh" }}
      whenCreated={setMap}
    >
    ...
}
```

Here is a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-leaflet-v-3-x-location-button-in-map-to-get-user-location-tlncn1?file=/src/Map.jsx:367-890). When you open it the icon won't show up cause there is a known issue with svg icons and codesandbox but locally you should not have any issue.

Comment: whenCreated has been removed in react-leaflet 4.x, replaced with: ref

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solve the same issue. Created a resusable component for leaflet controls. Just a fancy way to easily handle leaflets classes.

```js
import L from "leaflet";
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const ControlClasses = {
  bottomleft: "leaflet-bottom leaflet-left",
  bottomright: "leaflet-bottom leaflet-right",
  topleft: "leaflet-top leaflet-left",
  topright: "leaflet-top leaflet-right",
};

type ControlPosition = keyof typeof ControlClasses;
interface LeafLetControlProps {
  position?: ControlPosition;
}

const LeafletControl: React.FC<LeafLetControlProps> = ({
  position,
  children,
}) => {
  const divRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (divRef.current) {
      L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(divRef.current);
      L.DomEvent.disableScrollPropagation(divRef.current);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div ref={divRef} className={position && ControlClasses[position]}>
      <div className={"leaflet-control"}>{children}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LeafletControl;
```

Use the leaflet control component in with the functionality you want.

```js
import { ActionIcon } from "@mantine/core";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useMapEvents } from "react-leaflet";
import { CurrentLocation } from "tabler-icons-react";
import LeafletControl from "./LeafletControl";

interface LeadletMyPositionProps {}

const LeadletMyPosition: React.FC<LeadletMyPositionProps> = ({}) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const map = useMapEvents({
    locationfound(e) {
      map.flyTo(e.latlng);
      setLoading(false);
    },
  });

  return (
    <LeafletControl position={"topright"}>
      <ActionIcon
        onClick={() => {
          setLoading(true);
          map.locate();
        }}
        loading={loading}
        variant={"transparent"}
      >
        <CurrentLocation />
      </ActionIcon>
    </LeafletControl>
  );
};

export default LeadletMyPosition;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Disco's answer re-written in newer syntax and removing dependencies on external icons etc.

```
import L from "leaflet";
import { PropsWithChildren, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const ControlClasses = {
  bottomleft: "leaflet-bottom leaflet-left",
  bottomright: "leaflet-bottom leaflet-right",
  topleft: "leaflet-top leaflet-left",
  topright: "leaflet-top leaflet-right"
};

type ControlPosition = keyof typeof ControlClasses;
interface LeafLetControlProps {
  position?: ControlPosition;
}

export default function LeafletControl(
  props: PropsWithChildren<LeafLetControlProps>
) {
  const divRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (divRef.current) {
      L.DomEvent.disableClickPropagation(divRef.current);
      L.DomEvent.disableScrollPropagation(divRef.current);
    }
  });

  return (
    <div
      ref={divRef}
      className={props.position && ControlClasses[props.position]}>
      <div className={"leaflet-control leaflet-bar"}>{props.children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...and

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useMapEvents } from "react-leaflet";
import LeafletControl from "./LeafletControl";
import { IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import MyLocationIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MyLocation';

export default function LeafletMyPosition() {

  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  const map = useMapEvents({
    locationfound(e) {
      map.flyTo(e.latlng, 18, { duration: 2});
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  });

  return (
    <LeafletControl position={"bottomright"}>
        <IconButton
        size="small"
            disabled={isLoading}
            onClick={() => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            map.locate();
          }}
        >
            <MyLocationIcon />
        </IconButton>
    </LeafletControl>
  );
}
```

Used as follows:

```
 <MapContainer>
   <MapController />
    <TileLayer />
    <LeafletMyPosition />
 </MapContainer>
```